# how to allow only one check box to be checked in ngfor loop grid in angualr

Tags: angular, checkbox

i have checkboxes in grid as shown below ,but the issue is, it is allowing multiple check boxes to be selected every time which need to be restricted to one at a time .How can i do this?

```
<tr *ngFor="let remote of asyncNewLinkRemoteModel | async  | paginate: { id: 'activities', itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }">
                                                                    <td>                                                        
                                                                        <input type="checkbox"
                                                                        name="chkRmt"
                                                                        value="{{remote}}" (change)="setSelectedRmt(remote)"
                                                                         />
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>{{remote.REGION_CODE}}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{remote.REGION_SUB_CODE}}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{remote.SITE_ID}}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{remote.MW_CATEGORY}}</td>
                                                                </tr>
```

Comment: I am a bit rusty on angular right now but this might give you an idea https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNFvRJvPUv4

Answer (score 1):

I think you store the selected remote.

So disable other checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkRmt"
       value="{{remote}}" 
       (change)="setSelectedRmt(remote)"
       [disabled]="selectedRemote && selectedRemote != remote" />
```

Comment: Not to disable actually. One selection at a time

Comment: how to enable if i want to select other check box??

Comment: i did it by using [checked]="selectedRmt && selectedRmt == remote"

Answer (score 1):

if you has a variable,e.g.

```
value:any
```

You can use a input type checked with ngModel and modelChange

```
<tr*ngFor="let remote of asyncNewLinkRemoteModel | async ">
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="value==remote" 
                           (ngModelChange)="value=$event?remote :null">
    </td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

see that the variable "value" gets the value of remote if you check and the checkbox is true only if value gets the value of remote. If you "uncheck" "value" becomes null

Answer (score 0):

i did it by using     [checked]="selectedRmt && selectedRmt == remote"